# Subset Font By Specific Glyphs

Tags: unicode, fonts, font-face, webfonts, truetype

I have a 14MB TTF containing mostly Simplified Chinese characters.

I'd like to reduce the size by creating a subset which only contains the specific characters within an HTML page.

So, ideally, I'd like to pass a (Linux) program an block of text and have it recreate the font based on the characters contained.

E.g.

```
 ./magic-font-squisher input.tff "ABC123水小长"
```

or

```
 ./magic-font-squisher input.tff /path/to/test.html
```

The new font would then only have those 9 characters present.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have used https://bitbucket.org/philip/font-optimizer/src

```
./subset.pl --chars="ABC 123 水小长" input.ttf output.ttf
```

Which is exactly what I want.

**How I Found It**

[Google Font Directory](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/) contains a [subset](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/source/browse/tools/subset/subset.py) tool.  The [README](http://code.google.com/p/googlefontdirectory/source/browse/tools/subset/README) says

> --string=: Generate subset for just the specified string. Useful for
>   creating a menu subset. Generally we use subset.pl from Font
>   Optimizer for this, however.

A search for Font Optimizer took me to a [demo site](http://fonts.philip.html5.org/) which allows you to test the script.

There is also a [forked GitHub repo](https://github.com/fnp/librarian/blob/master/librarian/font-optimizer/subset.pl) which has better documentation.

Comment: subset.pl keeps returning```Wide character in subroutine entry at Font/Subsetter.pm line 1496.``` Any ideas?

Comment: The best answer is probably just to use FontForge, as that seems to be a living project. However, the github fork of the original repo appears to have been patched to fix this problem, so you should be able to use that. My only caveat is that is still throws a number of deprecation errors so may eventually also start breaking.

Comment: @terence-eden this answer not working at all. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54564504/clear-font-ttf-from-unused-glyphs

Answer (score 8):

You can do it by [scripting FontForge](http://fontforge.org/scripting.html). This works, though it can probably be made more clever or wrapped in a containing script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env fontforge
Open($1); # first param
SelectAll();
SelectFewer(0u41, 0u43, 0u31, 0u33); # a range
SelectFewer(0u6c34); # or a single codepoint
SelectFewer(0u5c0f);
SelectFewer(0u957f);
DetachAndRemoveGlyphs();
Save($2); # second param
Quit(0);
```

I had to define `FONTFORGE_LANGUAGE` before running it:

```
FONTFORGE_LANGUAGE=ff ./squish source.ttf squished.ttf
```

Comment: Newer documentation: [intro](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/tutorials/scripting/), [reference for functions](http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/documentation/scripting/native/scripting-alpha/). Also note that `SelectFewer(0u41, 0u43);` is range `[0u41, 0u43]`, and `SelectFewer(0u41, 0u43, 0u31, 0u33);` is union of two ranges, `[0u41, 0u43]` and `[0u31, 0u33]` (it is a bit unclear in answer). Also someone may wants compact font via command `Reencode('compacted');`. BTW, thanks for excellent answer!