# Clear font.ttf from unused glyphs

Tags: replace, truetype

For example I want to use this `.ttf` font file:
https://www.onlinewebfonts.com/download/3b2646a48566403a55f62ceddbecbe18

It contains 29,064 glyphs.

I want to leave in it only the letters I use.
A short example: `どこでもタップしてプレイ`

So, from 29,064 it will be only 12 characters left. In my actual situation if will be around 300 glyphs.

Basically, I want to dramatically decrease it's file-size by removing unused glyphs

Is there a way to implement this by some script? I'm on macOS.
Or some app can do this and how exactly? Is there a real life example?

upd: answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673426/subset-font-by-specific-glyphs) not working, throwing errors:

```
./subset.pl --chars="どこでもタップしてプレイ" /Users/User/Desktop/1.ttf /Users/User/Desktop/2.ttf
```

`Wide character in subroutine entry at Font/Subsetter.pm line 1496.`

In that question there are recommendation of use fixed this bug repo: https://github.com/fnp/librarian/blob/master/librarian/font-optimizer/subset.pl

And with it executing same command gives another errors:

`Uses unhandled table 'BASE'
Uses forbidden table 'CFF '`

As font file I used that from first link, just renamed it to `1.ttf`

Comment: Can you please tell us exactly what command you have run, and the exact error messages? That would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @terence-eden I edited question, added more explanation. Thank you.

Comment: I've taken a look, and that font seems to be broken. I can't properly open it in FontForge. I suggest contacting the author of the font to see if they can fix the problem. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: @terence-eden This font actually a font (included)[https://support.apple.com/hr-hr/HT206872] in macOS, from which I'm trying to subset it. But its `.ttc` file. Anyway, I'm looking any other Chinese(Simple, Tradit, Japanese) font which I'm able to subset.